# how do i parse string or extract text that lies between multi parentheses, colon, brackets, semi colon and much more special characters in c# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, parentheses, multiparameter

**how do i parse string or extract text that lies between multi parentheses, colon, brackets, semi colon and much more special characters in c# ASP.Net**

**string 1:**

```
{"ErrorCode":"000","ErrorMessage":"Success","JobId":"41099374",
"MessageData":[{"Number":"9999999999","MessageId":"JY15wKCbkkCZSEUssGRgmg"}]}
```

**string 2:**

```
{"ErrorCode":"21","ErrorMessage":"insufficient credits","JobId":null,"MessageData":null}
```

**Requirements:**
i want to fetch all the values

> examle: ErrorCode = 000

please help me.

Comment: This is a serialized object - deserialize it

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

Answer (score 1):

One way to deserialize this, using `Newtonsoft.Json` Nuget package, is like this:

```
var deserializedObject = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(File.ReadAllText("data.txt"));

var errorCodeValue = deserializedObject.ErrorCode;
```

Another way can be to use splits and loops but it will be tricky when you have collections...

Comment: @Er. PRAVEEN SAHU - Did this help you solve your problem?